# Is it possible to include multiple buckets as --trigger-resource for a google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to include two buckets as `-trigger-resource` for a `gcloud` function? I tried the following deployment, but it only seems to be listening to events occuring in the `bucket-2`.

```
gcloud functions deploy my-function \
--entry-point functions.MyFunction \
--runtime java11 \
--memory 512MB \
--trigger-resource gs://bucket-1 \
--trigger-resource gs://bucket-2 \
--trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--region=europe-west1
```

Would appreciate any sort of help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A single deployed function can only trigger on changes to a single bucket at a time.  If you want to trigger on multiple buckets, you can deploy the function once for each bucket.  You will have to give each function a different name and `--trigger-resource` flag, but everything else can stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

As [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--trigger-resource) doesn't suggest such option as multiple trigger resource it is not possible I believe.

If you don't want to create extra functions you can receive [bucket notifications in Pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes) and [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) your function on Pubsub events.